# Export module components in Python

Tags: python, import, module, julia

In Julia, it is possible to export a function (or a variable, struct, etc.) of a module, after which it can be called in another script without the namespace (once it has been imported). For example:

```
# helpers.jl
module helpers

function ordinary_function()
# bla bla bla
end

function exported_function()
# bla bla bla
end

export exported_function()
end
```

```
# main.jl
include("helpers.jl")
using .helpers

#we have to call the non-exported function with namespace
helpers.ordinary_function()

#but we can call the exported function without namespace
exported_function()
```

Is this feature available in Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python importing is easier than this:

```
# module.py
def foo(): pass

# file.py
from module import foo
foo()

# file2.py
from file import foo
foo()
```

This works with `class`es too.

---

In Python you can also do something like this:

```
import module
# You have to call like this:
module.foo()
```

---

When you import a module, all the functions the module imported are considered part of the module. Using the example below:

```
# file.py
import module

# file2.py
import file
file.module.foo()
# or...
from file import module
module.foo()
# ...or...
from file.module import foo
foo()
```

---

Notice that in Python the `export` is not needed.

Look at the [`documentation`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html): no `export` keyword exists in Python.

Comment: Yes, I have no issue with the importing mechanism in Python, I was just curious about whether this specific feature exists.

Comment: So I'm happy to announce you that yes, this feature exists. I'm going to edit the answer.

Comment: @JafarIsbarov, the answer is now complete, I hope it solved your curiosity.

Comment: Let me be more specific. Is there something I can do **within** the module, so that when the module is imported, the "exported" components can be called directly?

Comment: Oh, ok, now I understand. Let me edit...

Answer (score 5):

In Julia two modules can `export` the same function and Julia will automatically detect such an issue, i.e. even if you `export` them they will not overwrite each other:

```
julia> module A
       export x
       x() = "a"
       end
Main.A

julia> module B
       export x
       x() = "b"
       end
Main.B

julia> using .A, .B

julia> x()
WARNING: both B and A export "x"; uses of it in module Main must be qualified
```

That is why in Julia the common practice is to do `using` not `import`.

In Python doing an equivalent is considered to be a bad practice in production code.

As a side comment: another relevant difference between Julia and Python is that in Julia `module` concept is detached from the files/directory structure. You can have many modules in one file or you can have many files that form a single module.

Comment: I had forgot to specify that `from module import *` is considered a bad practice in Python. +1

Comment: I have added the comment (not the answer, as what @FLAK-ZOSO writes is an answer) to explain why in Julia having `export` makes sense and is often used (in short - Julia is able to track where some function was defined and thus automatically detect potential ambiguities).